# Kendo Grid not showing data with Index action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, kendo-grid, telerik-mvc

I am using Kendo Grid for MVC.

Following is my controller and actions.

```
public class ComplainController : Controller
{
    private MSMContext db = new MSMContext();

    public ActionResult Index([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var cOMPLAINs = db.COMPLAINs.Include(c => c.MASTER_FAULT);
        var model =  cOMPLAINs.Select(o => new
        {
            JOBSHEET_NO = o.JOBSHEET_NO,
            CUSTOMER_NAME = o.CUSTOMER_NAME,
            CUSTOMER_MOBILE = o.CUSTOMER_MOBILE,
            COMPANY_NAME = o.COMPANY_NAME,
            MODEL_NAME = o.MODEL_NAME
        });
        return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
    public ActionResult GetData([DataSourceRequest]DataSourceRequest request)
    {
        var model = db.COMPLAINs.Select(o => new
        {
            JOBSHEET_NO = o.JOBSHEET_NO,
            CUSTOMER_NAME = o.CUSTOMER_NAME,
            CUSTOMER_MOBILE = o.CUSTOMER_MOBILE,
            COMPANY_NAME = o.COMPANY_NAME,
            MODEL_NAME = o.MODEL_NAME
        });
        return Json(model.ToDataSourceResult(request), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

Now Following is my Kendo Grid Code I am using in a view.

```
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<WebMSM.Models.COMPLAIN>()
    .Name("grid")
    .Columns(columns =>
    {
        columns.Bound(p => p.JOBSHEET_NO).Width(150);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CUSTOMER_NAME).Width(400);
        columns.Bound(p => p.CUSTOMER_MOBILE).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(p => p.COMPANY_NAME).Width(200);
        columns.Bound(p => p.MODEL_NAME).Width(150);
    })
    .Pageable()
    .Sortable()
    .Scrollable()
    .Filterable()
    .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
    .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Complain"))
     )
    )
```

If I use `GetData` action, Kendo Grid is working fine with all data shown.
But if I use `Index` action, Kendo Grid displays but without data.
While using `Index` action, following `json` data is displayed without any page layout and `HTML`.

```
{"Data":[{"JOBSHEET_NO":1018,"CUSTOMER_NAME":"HEMAL RATHOD","CUSTOMER_MOBILE":"9825369987","COMPANY_NAME":"SAMSUNG","MODEL_NAME":"NOTE 3"},{"JOBSHEET_NO":1019,"CUSTOMER_NAME":"MUKESH CHAUHAN","CUSTOMER_MOBILE":"9825305305","COMPANY_NAME":"APPLE","MODEL_NAME":"IPHONE 6"}],"Total":2,"AggregateResults":null,"Errors":null}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("GetData", "Complain"))
 )
)
```

needs to be changed to

```
.DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
    .Ajax()
    .PageSize(20)
    .Read(read => read.Action("Index", "Complain"))
 )
)
```

if you want to get it working with "Index". If your datasource never calls "Index" action method, then your grid will always be empty.

Comment: Yes thats what i am asking, If I use `Index` as you said, I just get plain JSON data as shown in my question, no grid, no HTML. And thats my question.